Conditional Formatting based on text string in another column
NEVER MIND: I found my solution.
I found the following Conditional Formatting statement worked for me:  =ISNUMBER(SEARCH($M$1,$E2,1)), where I entered the word "Gold" in M1, then dragged the lower right select handle in column G all the way down.
Solution
===== ORIGINAL POST BELOW =====
I am using Microsoft 365 Excel.
I have two columns, E and G. In Column E, suppose the word "gold" appears, but not by itself, i.e. "gold (43/54)" or "BSG gold". There are also blank cells in this column and cells with other words, i.e. "silver".
I have a conditional formatting rule applied to Column E.
"Format only cells that contain", and in the rule description "Specific Text" "containing" "Gold".Column E Conditional Formatting
In Column G, I want to apply the same Conditional Formatting, in the same row as the word "gold" or the cell color found in Column E, so that if I need to change the word "gold" in Column E to "silver", the cell in the same row in column G changes as well.
Here is a sample of the work area.
Work Area example

Why do I always find the answer after I've posted? The following Conditional Formatting statement worked for me:  =ISNUMBER(SEARCH($M$1,$E2,1)), where I entered the word "Gold" in M1, then dragged the lower right select handle in column G all the way down.

Create an answer from that,[v] Answer my own question below.
